# How i can create multiple separate forms and get a pdf out of the querys of all the forms?

Tags: forms

im actually trying to build a complex form. It should look like this:

1. First form with some questions, textarea and standard form stuff
2. Some Wordpress elements i want to design with wordpress
3. Second form with some questions, textarea and standard form stuff
4. Some Wordpress elements ...
5. Third and last form where i can submit the form and get a pdf with the data out of all forms.

Also the form should save the data while typing, so i can type in a textarea in form 1 and it auto submits the information without reloading the page. And if i press the submit button on form3 i get a pdf with the data from form1. I know it is possible! And i know it is doable with cf7 and E2PDF, but i dont know exactly how. I was trying to use forminator due to better useability but it is not capable of this function.

Thank you very much
Best Regards

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for the some sort of similar problem, I created a plugin to generate custom submission ID in the forminator hidden field now the it does not work with E2pdf to create a pdf :.